# Populate django select on/after validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an Django form with a drop down that is being dynamically populated with ajax-chosen.
The form class looks like this:

```
class SightingForm(ModelForm):

ajax_bird = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Bird", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'longdropdown chosenBirds', 'data-placeholder': 'Select a Bird'}, choices=DEFAULT_BIRDS) )
new_photo = forms.ImageField(required=False, label="Photo")
class Meta:
    model = Sighting
    fields = ('ajax_bird','count',)

def clean_ajax_bird(self):
    ajax_bird = self.cleaned_data['ajax_bird']
    abi = 0
    try:
        abi = int(ajax_bird)
        bird = Bird.get_bird(abi)
        if bird is None:
            raise Exception
    except Exception as ex:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please select a bird.")
    return ajax_bird

def clean(self):
    super(forms.ModelForm, self).clean()
    try:
        ab = self.cleaned_data['ajax_bird']
        if int(ab) > 0:
            bird = Bird.get_bird(int(ab))
            self.ajax_bird.widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'longdropdown chosenBirds', 'data-placeholder': 'Select a Bird'}, choices=((str(bird.id), str(bird.common_name),),))
        return self.cleaned_data
    except:
        """fail silently"""
```

Everything is working fine until validation. If anything else on the page does not validate, the ajax_bird field will no longer be populated with the users choice (since it was produced by ajax the first time around).

In the clean method you might see what I am trying to do. I would like to change the default choices based on what was chosen in the ajax drop down. Is there any clean way to do this?